# Unable to change collectionview cell background colour in Swift

Tags: swift, constraints, uicollectionviewcell, background-color

I have given constraints for image and label like this

[Image constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmF7A.png). [Label Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oulWq.png)

**code:** with this code i am able to get `selectedNamesArray` but unable to change cell colour. where am i wrong? is there anything wrong in storyboard constraints so that cell BG is not changing? or any other coding mistake? could anyone please explain the issue and the solution for cell background change

```
class TestCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var roundImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    roundImg.layer.cornerRadius = roundImg.frame.width / 2
    roundImg.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    roundImg.clipsToBounds = true
}
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self

let layOut = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layOut.scrollDirection = .vertical

collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layOut
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
GenericCodableServicecall()
}

var cvWidth: CGFloat = -1.0

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
if cvWidth != collectionView.frame.size.width {
    cvWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width
    if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

        let nColumns: Int = 4
        
        let sideSpace: CGFloat = fl.sectionInset.left + fl.sectionInset.right
        
        let totalEmptyspace: CGFloat = sideSpace + (CGFloat(nColumns) * 3.0)
        
        let w = (cvWidth - totalEmptyspace) / CGFloat(nColumns)
        fl.itemSize = .init(width: w, height: w)

        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
    }
}
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
namesArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionCell
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.titleLbl.text = namesArray[indexPath.row]
return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)     {

print("in select..")

let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! TestCollectionCell
let selectedName = namesArray[indexPath.row]
if let inx = selectedNamesArray.firstIndex(of: selectedName){
    selectedNamesArray.remove(at: inx)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
else{
    selectedNamesArray.append(selectedName)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}
print(selectedNamesArray)
}
```

unable to change cell background when i select/deselect always showing green background only.

**EDIT:**

```
// MARK: - TestAPIModel
struct TestAPIModel: Codable {
let page, perPage, total, totalPages: Int
var data: [Datum]
let support: Support

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case page
    case perPage = "per_page"
    case total
    case totalPages = "total_pages"
    case data, support
}
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
let id: Int
let name: String
let year: Int
let color, pantoneValue: String
var isSelected: Bool = false
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, name, year, color
    case pantoneValue = "pantone_value"
    case isSelected = "is_selected"

}
}
```

after changing model like above o/p:

> decodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "is_selected", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "is_selected", intValue: nil) ("is_selected").", underlyingError: nil)))))

**this is my serviceCAll case here how to check nil data** please guide

var jsonData: TestAPIModel? {
didSet{
print(jsonData?.data)
}

```
}

NetworkService.request("https://reqres.in/api/unknown", method: .get, parameters: parameters) { (result: Result<TestAPIModel, APIError>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            print("response \(user)")
            self.jsonData = user
            self.collectionView.reloadData()

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra array for the `selected` state is very bad practice. It's cumbersome to maintain and you have to set the color accordingly in `cellForItemAt` because cells are reused when the user scrolls.

A better way is a struct for the data source with a member `isSelected`

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    var isSelected = false
}
```

Then the data source array is

```
var people = [Person]()
```

and the data source and methods are

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    people.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TestCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionCell
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    let person = people[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLbl.text = person.name
    cell.backgroundColor = person.isSelected ? .red : .yellow
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelect` just toggle `isSelected` of the item at given `indexPath` and reload the item

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)     {

    print("in select..")

    people[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Comment: here you have created `Person` struct. but i have added namesArray with `JSON DATA` like this  `self.namesArray = user.data.compactMap { $0.name }`.
 so where should i add `isSelected` variable?

Comment: i have updated my code with Model and o/p

Comment: In the object representing an item in `data`. Add `CodingKeys` and omit `isSelected` because it's not part of the JSON and delete `.compactMap { $0.name }`.

Comment: is it possible to add isSelected in jsonModel? or should i create new struct with `name and isSelected` variables?

Comment: Yes, delete `case isSelected = "is_selected"` in the CodingKeys. A new struct is not needed.

Comment: okay thank you, but how to check nil, i have added my service call code at the bottom of the code please once look at it and guide me to check nil. i am unable to check.

Comment: i am using jsonData.data.count and `cell.titleLbl.text = jsonData?.data[indexPath.row].name` like this

Comment: Declare the data source array **non-optional** `var data = [Datum]()` and assign `self.data  = user.data` in the completion handler of the request. Then use  `data.count` and `cell.titleLbl.text = data[indexPath.row].name`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! TestCollectionCell
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white (What ever color u want change)
```

Comment: your code also correct.. but i cant upvote

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.